# Creating a reset button for an inline radio button group

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a reset button for an inline radio button group.
I'm not satisfied with the result because there is no space between the last option and the button.

```
<div>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
        <input data-bind="checked: sex" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptionssex" id="inlineRadiosex1" value="1"> M
    </label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
        <input data-bind="checked: sex" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptionssex" id="inlineRadiosex2" value="2"> F
    </label>
    <label class='radio-inline'>
        <input data-bind="checked: sex" type="radio" name="inlineRadioOptionssex" id="inlineRadiosex3" value="3"> O
    </label>
    <button data-bind="click: resetsex" class="btn btn-default btn-xs btn-round"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button>
</div>
```

The result is the following:

[image: Inline radio button group with reset button]

What is the cleanest way to insert some space between the last option and the button ?

Comment: did you try `margin-left`?

Comment: Nope, I didn't and it does the trick indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4esuc20k/) demonstrating the use of `margin-left`

```
button.reset-btn{
  margin-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: This applies to all buttons on the page

Comment: umm you can add class to button, wait updating the fiddle.